# ¿Cómo crear ruta con la api de Google maps teniendo varias coordenadas de destino, y que muestre un nombre personalizado en cada parada de la ruta?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Tengo varios clientes (mas de 5 mil) ubicados con coordenadas, los cuales se visitan en una ruta especifica, he logrado utilizar Google Maps creando la URL con la ubicación actual y los puntos para cada cliente, lo he separado en pequeñas rutas para mejorar a la hora de realizar la visita, los clientes están ordenados y los puntos en la ruta se muestran según el orden del cliente. La ruta la construyo generando un un link como este: [https://www.google.com/maps/dir/[lat-origen],[long-origen]/[lat-dest-1],[long-dest-1]/[lat-dest-2],[long-dest-2]/[lat-dest-3],[long-dest-3]/[lat-dest-n],[long-dest-n]](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/%5Blat-origen%5D,%5Blong-origen%5D/%5Blat-dest-1%5D,%5Blong-dest-1%5D/%5Blat-dest-2%5D,%5Blong-dest-2%5D/%5Blat-dest-3%5D,%5Blong-dest-3%5D/%5Blat-dest-n%5D,%5Blong-dest-n%5D), es funcional únicamente en navegador web. En la imagen 1 se ve como se muestra actualmente.

En la 2nda imagen muestro un ejemplo que encontré (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints#maps_directions_waypoints-javascript) y el código que utiliza donde se muestra las letras A, B, C, D de los puntos de cada ruta, que es donde quiero que se muestre el nombre de los  clientes

```js
function initMap() {
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 },
  });

  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  const waypts = [];
  const checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");

  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
      waypts.push({
        location: checkboxArray[i].value,
        stopover: true,
      });
    }
  }

  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: document.getElementById("start").value,
      destination: document.getElementById("end").value,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

      const route = response.routes[0];
      const summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions-panel");

      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";

      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (let i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        const routeSegment = i + 1;

        summaryPanel.innerHTML +=
          "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br>";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br>";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br><br>";
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
}
```

Ahora necesito su ayuda en 2 puntos:

1. Poder agregar los nombres de los clientes en cada punto del mapa (IMPORTANTE!!!)
2. Que se pueda ver en la app de Google Maps (seria excelente pero no es importante)

[image: Ruta Clientes 1-a]

[image: Mapa ejemplo]